# Issue with Spring Data (Spring Boot) and Joda Time field mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jodatime

I have some entities with Joda DateTime fields.
When trying to start the application, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.integrate(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:192) ~[usertype.spi-6.0.1.GA.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
```

I tried to put

```
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true
```

in the application.properties and it didn't work. So I added the Hibernate annotation into my entity class:

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime from;
```

and it didn't work.

My pom.xml (partial):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson json data bind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I also tried Jadira usertype.core 6.0.0.GA, 5.0.0.GA and 4.0.0.GA but nothing changes. How can I fix that?

====================EDIT
Debugging led me to line 192 of the class `AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator`

```
 String isEnabled = (String)sessionFactory.getProperties().get("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes");
```

My debugger says the value assigned to `isEnabled` is the "true". However, the execution jumps to the finally clause: `ConfigurationHelper.setCurrentSessionFactory((SessionFactory)null)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties() changed in 5.2 to return Map rather than Properties. This leads to a NoSuchMethodError if hibernate version is lower than that. And also make sure to use latest jadira jar which is compatible with Hibernate 5.2

Add these dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the above issue is that you forgot to add the entitiyManager dependency.

Try adding the below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me with spring boot, the problem is that Spring boot version 1.5.4  data-jpa starter has  hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager version 5.0.12 which is incompatible with jadira version 6.0.1.GA so we have to override these in pom.xml and provide version 5.2.0.Final at least ( I have used 5.2.10.Final in the code as this is the latest one at the time of writting).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson json data bind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring boot version 1.5.4  has  hibernate-core 5.0.12 which is incompatible with jadira version 6.0.1.GA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring boot version 1.5.4  has  hibernate-entitymanager 5.0.12 which is incompatible with jadira version 6.0.1.GA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```