# Oracle Timestamp/Date mapping problem with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Getting issues while mapping my table. I am using Oracle DB, my table ->> test_time is using 2 columns(originally I only want to store the date, hence used Date but did'nt work) using Timestamp type in table.
Below is my Model class, I have tried java.sql.Date class when I was using Date type in oracle, it did not worked. Now I am using java.util.Date class as I am using Timestamp in Oracle, it is still not working. Not able to understand, what should I actually do, to make it work.

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

@Entity
@Table(name = "test_time ")
public class TestTime 
{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CUST_SEQ1")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "edu_id", allocationSize = 1, name = "CUST_SEQ1")
    private int edu_id;


    @JsonSerialize(as = Date.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date batch_start_year;

    @JsonSerialize(as = Date.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date batch_end_year;


    public int getEdu_id() {
        return edu_id;
    }

    public void setEdu_id(int edu_id) {
        this.edu_id = edu_id;
    }

    public Date getBatch_start_year() {
        return batch_start_year;
    }

    public void setBatch_start_year(Date batch_start_year) 
    {
        this.batch_start_year = batch_start_year;
    }

    public Date getBatch_end_year() {
        return batch_end_year;
    }

    public void setBatch_end_year(Date batch_end_year) {
        this.batch_end_year = batch_end_year;
    }

}
```

I have added a data in the table, to check get method for this. It is neither insert anything nor get anything from the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Joda-Time library. [Download it from maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time).

You have to update your two date columns as below:

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private DateTime batch_start_year;

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private DateTime batch_end_year;
```

Here `DateTime` should be `org.joda.time.DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used in the same way, it gives me class not found error on "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime" and when I have added the below dependecy for the same:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.extended -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.extended</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
It gives me another error: Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Comment: Can you try again with these two versions: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.core/6.0.1.GA and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9. Add these both dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Anuradha, the error went, but somehow when I am using this Jadira liberary, my postmapping method is not working. Like it does not called from server. Otherwise it is working. My requested URL is correct.

Comment: Great. But It is impossible post mapping not work due to the Jadira library.

Comment: May be this will help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880292/issue-with-spring-data-spring-boot-and-joda-time-field-mapping

Comment: I don't know, it does not give me any error neither give any output. On browser I see "HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request" which must come if I am sending a request in the wrong path, but I am not. I removed this and then tried, it worked. 
I don't know what will be issue in my case at this moment.

Comment: Better to debug and check. But I am sure Jadira library isn't the reason for that.

Comment: Sure, Thanks. It work for me(now calling post method). I guess it was wrong liberary issue. 
But still it does not insert into DB.

Comment: If you can provide the console error, may be I can help you.

Comment: That's the problem, there is no error. Hibernate does not run the insert statement at all.

Comment: Better way is the debug and check why insert statement isn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

My startDate and endDate in DB is of Timestamp data type and Similarly in my Model class.
One don't really have to use different libraries. For me it worked with java.sql.Timestamp class (since, I am using Oracle7 jar for oracle 12 c), you can use joda time or java.util.Date as well based on your requirements. 
For me, it was not showing the changes in the database because I did not commit my changes. SO I add the session.flush();
you can add either commit()/flush() or you can add the hibernate property.

Model class

````
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

@Entity
@Table(name = "test_time ")
public class TestTime 
{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CUST_SEQ1")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "edu_id", allocationSize = 1, name = "CUST_SEQ1")
    private int edu_id;


  @JsonSerialize(as = Timestamp.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
    private Timestampbatch_start_year;

    @JsonSerialize(as = Timestamp.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
    private Timestampbatch_end_year;


    public int getEdu_id() {
        return edu_id;
    }

    public void setEdu_id(int edu_id) {
        this.edu_id = edu_id;
    }

    public Timestamp getBatch_start_year() {
        return batch_start_year;
    }

    public void setBatch_start_year(Timestamp batch_start_year) 
    {
        this.batch_start_year = batch_start_year;
    }

    public Timestamp getBatch_end_year() {
        return batch_end_year;
    }

    public void setBatch_end_year(Timestamp batch_end_year) {
        this.batch_end_year = batch_end_year;
    }

} ```



And when I am inserting date into DB:

```sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user_edu);

            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

            return user_edu.getEdu_id(); ```
````